# Get value from another table where join column isn't unique

Tags: mysql

I have a SQL query where I need to get most of my columns from Table A and 1 column from Table B. I'm using a non-unique value to join the two tables.

The one column I need from table B is a date. How can I make it so that the query returns the maximum date value from the multiple rows found in table B if any of them have a date. If none of them have a date, I'd want it to return null.

Here's what my query looks like

```
SELECT A.ID,
A.field1,
A.field2,
B.date
FROM TableA A
LEFT JOIN TableB B
ON A.ID = B.ID
```

Right now, it's returning

```
ID, field1, field2, date
1   a       a       null
1   a       a       1/1/2014
1   a       a       1/1/2015
2   b       b       null
2   b       b       null
2   b       b       null
```

What I'd like it to return is

```
ID, field1, field2, date
1   a       a       1/1/2015
2   b       b       null
```

Since each ID from A returns multiple rows in B, I just want the date value from the row with the largest date (or null if none contain a value for date).

Answer (score 2):

use a MAX and a GROUP BY

```
SELECT 
  A.ID,
  A.field1,
  A.field2,
  MAX(B.date) as maxDate
FROM TableA A
LEFT JOIN TableB B
  ON A.ID = B.ID
GROUP BY   
  A.ID,
  A.field1,
  A.field2
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try adding GROUP BY   A.ID,  A.field1,  A.field2 at the end of query to get the right results.

Comment: Will this know to choose the entry that contains the newest date? In my example, would it return the value 1/1/2015 for the ID 1

Comment: No, in that case it will return 
ID, field1, field2, date
1   a       a       1/1/2015
1   a       a        null 
2   b       b       null

Since we are grouping it using the ID.

Answer (score 0):

Below should also work

```
SELECT A.ID,
A.field1,
A.field2,
(SELECT MAX(B.date) FROM TableB B   WHERE B.id= A.id GROUP BY id) maxDate
FROM TableA A
```